# Why do JDBC drivers register themselves in the classes' static initializer?

Tags: java, jdbc

What's the logic behind using `Class.forName()` to load a JDBC driver, instead of the drivers providing some static method to do the same thing?

For example, why not instead call `SomeDriverClass.loadDriver();` and continue to get a connection normally? Any reason the call to `java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver()` couldn't happen that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way the code doesn't need to have the driver class in the classpath during compile time. You don't want to have countless different JDBC drivers of the past, current and the future in the compile time classpath to make your JDBC code compatible with all of those databases. You don't want to recompile the code everytime you upgrade/replace the driver or DB. All you need is the driver class name in a `String` which can be configured externally (usually a properties or xml file).

In other words: portability and reusability.

If it is for your own private use, do whatever you want. But if you did it in a library which is to be distributed in public (e.g. an ORM or some database management tool), it won't become popular because the enduser has to grab the source code and change/recompile it everytime when it didn't support their database.

Comment: Interfaces resolve this, so instead of declaring a concrete class, you do something like databaseDriver.load() and use IOC to inject the driver implementation.

Example IDatabaseDriver driver = IOCContainer.getDriver();
driver.load();

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Service Provider Framework.The class of the object returned by a static factory method need not even exist at the time the class containing the method is written. This allows for a placeholder where multiple implementation could be plugged in at run time.

A service provider framework is a system in which multiple service providers implement a service, and the system makes the implementations available to its clients, decoupling them from the implementations.

If its somedriver.loadDriver() then the implementation is tightly coupled.